# How To Hide TitleBar in Visual Studio Extensibility Package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I am creating a Visual Studio Extensibility Package.  I am trying to create a ToolWindow which has no title bar. 
I don't want the Minimize, Maximize or Close buttons to be available. I want to handle the Close etc functions by buttons 
within my user control. Could someone please let me know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This works with standard windows forms. Theoretically it should be the same with VS Extensibility.... I would go check myself, but I don't have extensibility tools installed currently.

To hide the frame completely, you can click on your form, go to the form options, and set `FormBorderStyle = None`. From here, you can design a replacement bar on your form itself.

Just a warning: Once you do this, you will find that you cannot move your window around the screen. To fix this, apply this code to whatever control you have that replaces your title bar...

Namespace Declarations:

`Using System.Drawing;`

Global variables:

```
//Declare the variables that allow you to drag the form
private bool dragging;
private Point dragAt = Point.Empty;
```

Methods

```
//This method is called when you have locked onto a control so you can drag the form around
public void Pick(Control control, int x, int y)
{
    dragging = true;
    dragAt = new Point(x, y);
    control.Capture = true;
}

//This method is called when you release the control
public void Drop(Control control)
{
    dragging = false;
    control.Capture = false;
}
```

Control Handlers -- these go on whatever control you use to hold your new toolbar. Alternatively, you can make these generic handlers (instead of `ObjectName_WhatItHandles` you can name them `WhatItHandlesHandler`) and assign them to any control that fires `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`, and `MouseMove` events.

```
//This method is called whenever the mouse button is held down
private void TableLayoutPanel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Pick((Control)sender, e.X, e.Y);
}

//This method is called whenever the mouse button is released
private void TableLayoutPanel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Drop((Control)sender);
}

//This method is called when you move the mouse around
private void TableLayoutPanel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dragging)
    {
        Left = e.X + Left - dragAt.X;
        Top = e.Y + Top - dragAt.Y;
    }
    else dragAt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
```